# Change of observer vs change of reference frame

Tags: reference-frames, coordinate-systems, observers

I read this statement **"A change in observer affects the points in space-time and not the coordinates of points. However, a change of reference frame changes the coordinates of points (and not the points themselves) and is simply governed by a coordinate transformation."**

Source: *Nonlinear Solid Mechanics: A Continuum Approach for Engineering Science G. Holzapfel*

I don't understand in what way are the points affected with the change of observer if their coordinates didn't change knowing that each observer has its own reference frame.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the context from which the quoted sentence was extracted, it is hard to know what its author meant. However, I assume what they meant was as follows...

Suppose you have an observer in London recording their observations using a map centred on London. If the observer switches to using a map centred on Paris, the observer's real position doesn't change (they are still in London) and the surroundings they observe do not change- all that has changed is that the observer uses a new set of map references to label what they see. However, if the observer changes to one in Paris, the position of the observer and what they observe have changed in a real sense, regardless of whether they use a map centred on London or one centred on Paris to refer to the coordinates of their observations.

Comment: I agree that context is needed.   However, I don't understand your reasoning.  Paris will always be where it is, and so will London.  Their positions to not change.

Comment: No, but if the observer moves from one to the other their position certainly does change.

Comment: @garyp I think what the original text means, is that location of Paris relative to the observer changes, if the observer relocates from London to Paris.